# No sound on right ear on Motorola G4

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, audio, motorola-moto-g-4g

I was having an issue this morning with my Moto G4 and thought there could be more victims.

I could only hear the sound from the left speaker of my headphones.

So what was causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.

At first I wanted to try and fix it physically with the help of [this](https://de.ifixit.com/Guide/Motorola+Moto+G+1st+Generation+Headphone+Jack+Replacement/33109) tutorial and as I was building a thing out of cupboard I went to search the internet again.

And then I stumbled about [this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G4-Moto-G4-Plus-Moto-G4/Headphone-jack-problems-moto-g4/td-p/3360475) where someone said, restarting the phone made it work again for him.

This fixed my issue so I came to the conclusion that this is a software issue/bug.

I hope this helps somebody else.

For me it was very annoying because I only have this phone for two weeks.
So restart your phone every once in a while or you won't hear anything soon ;)